# Glimpse DLL Version on NuGet different than signature

Tags: dll, nuget, glimpse

Installed a new .NET35 Website project with Glimpse.WebForms and am getting a strange issue where the update checker thinks it is out of date.

There is a bug with the version checker..

Question: has anyone else encountered this?

[image]

And then in Glimpse I get this warning:

[image]

Comment: What actions did you perform when installing (i.e. just installed the latest WebForms package)? I'm wanting to try and replicate the problem.

Comment: Will repro exactly what I did on Monday and get back to you.

Comment: Ahh I figured it out.  I'd upgraded a website project from VS2010.  If I start afresh with a new .NET35 website project in VS2013 then all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Start afresh with a new .NET35 website project in VS2013 then all works as expected